# Align duplicated values to the same row by using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use the combination of IF, AND & MATCH functions to check whether or not those data are exactly the same as shown below. How to align them to the same row after that by using VBA in Excel?

P/S: I found another thread with a similar question. Yet, that's by inserting a new column which I don't want.

```
=IF(AND(MATCH(I:I,A:A,0),MATCH(J:J,B:B,0),MATCH(K:K,C:C,0),MATCH(L:L,D:D,0),MATCH(M:M,E:E,0)),"Match","Not Match")

A   B   C   D   E               I   J   K   L   M
---------------------------------------------------
A   1   1   1   1               B   2   2   2   2
B   2   2   2   2               K   11  11  11  11
C   3   3   3   3               I   9   9   9   9
D   4   4   4   4               H   8   8   8   8
E   5   5   5   5               A   1   1   1   1
F   6   6   6   6               C   3   3   3   3
G   7   7   7   7               E   5   5   5   5
H   8   8   8   8               D   4   4   4   4
I   9   9   9   9                               
J   10  10  10  10                              
K   11  11  11  11                              
L   12  12  12  12
```

This is the expected result.

```
A   B   C   D   E               I   J   K   L   M         O
-------------------------------------------------------------
A   1   1   1   1               A   1   1   1   1       Match
B   2   2   2   2               B   2   2   2   2       Match
C   3   3   3   3               C   3   3   3   3       Match
D   4   4   4   4               D   4   4   4   4       Match
E   5   5   5   5               E   5   5   5   5       Match
F   6   6   6   6                                       
G   7   7   7   7                                       
H   8   8   8   8               H   8   8   8   8       Match
I   9   9   9   9               I   9   9   9   9       Match
J   10  10  10  10                                      
K   11  11  11  11              K   11  11  11  11      Match
L   12  12  12  12
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the two ranges first, then run the code below:

```
Sub Matchrows()
'Matches two ranges by inserting lines in both ranges so each value is on the same line

'you first need to
'   sort the two data blocks on the first column
'   select the two data blocks you want to split and match

Dim rg1 As range, rg2 As range, firstMatch As Boolean
Dim i As Long, j As Long, foundRow As Long

application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If selection.Areas.Count <> 2 Then
        MsgBox "Select two areas"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rg1 = selection.Areas(1)
    Set rg2 = selection.Areas(2)

    'gets the number of unique values in the first rows of range 1 and 2, to be able to run the loop all the way
    Dim cUnique As New Collection

    On Error Resume Next

    With rg1
        For i = 1 To .Columns(1).Cells.Count
            cUnique.Add .Cells(i, 1), CStr(.Cells(i, 1))
        Next
    End With

    With rg2
        For i = 1 To .Columns(1).Cells.Count
            cUnique.Add .Cells(i, 1), CStr(.Cells(i, 1))
        Next
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    'boolean needed to be able to resize range 2 if required
    firstMatch = True

    For i = 1 To cUnique.Count
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rg1.Rows(i)) = 0 _
            Or WorksheetFunction.CountA(rg2.Rows(i)) = 0 _
            Or rg1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, rg2.Column - rg1.Column) = rg1.Cells(i, 1) Then
                firstMatch = False
                GoTo nxt_i:
        End If

        On Error Resume Next
        foundRow = rg2.Columns(1).Find(What:=rg1.Cells(i, 1), LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

        If Err <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            rg1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, rg2.Column - rg1.Column).Resize(, rg2.Columns.Count).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            If firstMatch Then Set rg2 = rg2.Offset(-1).Resize(rg2.Rows.Count + 1)
        Else
            If i < foundRow Then
                rg1.Offset(i - 1).Cut Cells(foundRow, rg1.Column)
            Else
                rg2.Rows(foundRow - rg2.Row + 1).Cut
                rg2.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If

            firstMatch = False
        End If

nxt_i:

    Next

application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```